# Chart.js - How do I dynamically change bar's stack

Tags: chart.js

I'm running into an issue while trying to switch a bar between stacks.

When I change the "stack" property of a dataset and update() the chart it doesn't actually change.  While testing things out I found that if I change the "stack" and type (to line), update(), and change the type back (to bar) and update() it displays correctly.

I've put a jsfiddle together:  https://jsfiddle.net/scutchs/m2gv3e90/

I think I'm updating properties correctly because I do see color changes (among other changes) but can't get the "Stack" change to show unless I force some type of full redraw of the dataset by changing its type.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Anyone else seen this behavior and have a solution or better work around?

Code looks like this...

````
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [
        'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr'
    ],
    datasets:[
        {
        label: 'Bananas',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        data: [10,20,30,15],
        stack: 'fruit'
      },
      {
        label: 'Grapes',
        backgroundColor: 'purple',
        data: [20,10,10,16],
        stack: 'fruit'
      },
      {
        label: 'Green Beans',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        data: [15,15,15,22],
        stack: 'veggie'
      },
      {
        label: 'Squash',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        data: [13,20,25,11],
        stack: 'veggie'
      },
      {
        label: 'Tomatoes',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        data: [13,20,25,11],
        stack: 'veggie'
      }
    ],
    options:{
        responsive: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});

//This changes the color but fails to change the Stack
$('#btnMoveTomato').on('click', function(){
    //changing color just to show that we are changing chart elements
    myChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor='darkred';
  myChart.data.datasets[4].stack='fruit';
  myChart.update();
});

//This changes the color and stack 
$('#btnMoveTomato2').on('click', function(){
    myChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor='pink';
  myChart.data.datasets[4].stack='fruit';

  //by changing type and updating it must be forcing a total redraw of the dataset?
    myChart.data.datasets[4].type='line';
    myChart.update();
    myChart.data.datasets[4].type='bar';

    myChart.update();
});

//this resets 
$('#btnResetTomato').on('click', function(){
    myChart.data.datasets[4].backgroundColor='red';
  myChart.data.datasets[4].stack='veggie';

    myChart.data.datasets[4].type='line';
    myChart.update();
    myChart.data.datasets[4].type='bar';

    myChart.update();
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the stack isn't updating or why changing the type helps in your example.

The way I do this is to completely remove the dataset and then add a new dataset as I've never had a need to just change the stack, usually all of the dataset gets updated:-

Removing a dataset:-

```
function removeDataset(chart, label) {
  chart.data.datasets = chart.data.datasets.filter(function(obj) {
    return (obj.label != label);
  });

  chart.update();
}
```

Adding a dataset:-

```
function addDataset(chart, dataset) {
  chart.data.datasets.push(dataset);

  chart.update();
}
```

I have added a fork to your fiddle to demonstrate this working https://jsfiddle.net/u21vw9sh/

Comment: Thanks for the work around.  That feels cleaner than what I was doing.  I'm going to leave this open a bit longer to see if anyone has a better explanation for what is wrong with the Stack setting, or the approach I was taking.  Seems like all the changes are reflected in the chart with the exception of Stack.